# How do I map the goto match command to v in vim? Effiencent moving in vim

Tags: vim

I notice that I use the goto match bracket key a ton in vim and it is really inconvenient to have it bound to the % key.  Since I don't use visual mode that often (and if I do I'm manually transitioned to it when I use my mouse) I would like to map this command to my v key.

As a side question does anyone have their ^ (go to beginning of line) and $ (go to end of line) mapped to different more convenient keys?

I guess the main problem that I'm having is that I use ^ % $ very frequently and I would like them to be mapped to more convenient keys so that I can move around more efficiently.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the deal? Use

```
map v %
```

In this way you can also map `^` and `$` keys. For example, I prefer to map `^` to the `Home` key:

```
nmap <Home> ^
imap <Home> <Esc>I
```

Comment: Moving around is so easy with hjkl I'm trying to do the same thing with the bracket, goto end, and goto beginning functions. That way im not moving shift and then 5 everytime I want to hope brackets.  I know its not that much time but it would but me in the flow me I think.

Comment: I understund why you want those keys to be mapped. Read my post, I wrote how you can do this. It's up to you now to choose the keys you want. You can map nearly all the keys in vim using `*map`